# Jquery blinking title

Tags: javascript, jquery

So, i need to have a blinking title, this code should work, but for some reason it doesn't.

Now console keeps showing me correct title, but title in my browsers doesn't change, what could be wrong?

```
var blink = true;

setInterval(function(){
    if(blink){
        $("title").text("test");
        blink = false;
        console.log($("title"));
    }else{
        $("title").text("");
        blink = true;
        console.log($("title"));
    }
}, 1000);
```

Comment: `"#title"` refers to `id="title"` for example. "title" may not refer to `document.title`. Can you show us the html definition of the `<title>` tag?

Comment: The code works for me as-is in FF11, of course an empty `<title>` just shows the URL instead, might want to try something like `<tons of spaces><dot>`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `document.title = ...` <---

You are just editing an attribute which does nothing.

---

Try this:

```
setInterval(function(){
    var title = document.title;
    document.title = (title == "test" ? "none" : "test");
}, 1000);
```

See the title in this [demo](http://fiddle.jshell.net/maniator/xDPHw/show/) change from `test` to `none` every second. ([full fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/xDPHw/))

Comment: How is `$("title")` different than `document.title` here? What do you mean "You are just editing an attribute"? You code works (so does the Op's, for me at least), but your explanation doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: thank you, still it's quite strange that jquery `text` function doesn't do the job.

Comment: @Madmartigan `<title>` is just an attribute of the page. It is like editing anything in the `head` tag which does **nothing**.

Comment: @Linas see the above comment ^^^

Comment: @Linas also you may notice that i ditched the `blink` variable that you had used in the OP.

Comment: well it seems, that i can't set my title to an empty space if i set it to any letter it works perfectly.

Comment: @Neal: Tell me if this works for you (it's the original code with `$('title')`): http://wesleymurch.com/test/9830886.php

Comment: @Linas yea, that is why in my demo I used none and test. ill update my answer.

Comment: @Neal: Ah, in Chrome and IE9 it only changes once to "test". In Firefox it works fine. Same with your code though.... What browser are you using? EDIT: They both only "don't work" in those browsers using an empty string.

Comment: @Madmartigan I am using chrome. did you click on the demo link?

Comment: @Neal: Yes I did and it works as long as you set a non-empty value. Check this again and tell me if it works (OP's code, but with non-empty value, I had trouble in jsfiddle getting it to work): http://wesleymurch.com/test/9830886.php (btw, nmdv)

Comment: Yep it works. That prob was the issue @Madmartigan, deleting my answer. you should post urs as an answer.

Comment: @Madmartigan let me know when I can delete.

Comment: @Neal: I'm not interested in posting an answer and am not sure what the explanation is (of why empty string did not work), feel free to add the info to yours.

Answer (score 1):

Use a direct reference:

```
var blink = true;

setInterval(function(){
var theTitle = document.getElementsByTagName("title")[0];
if(blink){
    theTitle.text = "test";
    //or theTitle.innerHTML = "test";
    blink = false;
}else{
    theTitle.text = "";
    //or theTitle.innerHTML = "";
    blink = true;
}
}, 1000);
```

Comment: This will not work at all. You **cannot** set a DOM object equal to a string.

Comment: @Neal he is actually just assigning stuff to a variable :P

Comment: @Neal - Of course you are correct, I had originally thought to assign the inside text to var theTitle and somehow left it out. Here are two options for setting the title.

Comment: @TravisJ There is **no such DOM object attribute** called `text`

Comment: Actually `HTMLTitleElement` does have `.text`, there is no jQuery here at all. `jQuery.text` would do `.innerText` or `.textContent` props anyway

Comment: @Esailija - I was under the impression `.text` was valid in that I have used it multiple times before. Thank you for the information that it is in fact valid. Unfortunately some people are too negative for their own good (you know who you are).